# How do you repair a SQL Server MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER default instance SQL Server directory after resetting my PC?

Tags: sql-server

I had freshly wiped my computer after backing up some folders.

I realized this was a mistake because I didn't look up to properly back up my SQL Server so now I only have the **MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER** server directory.

Is it possible to restore this SQL server directory and be able to access the databases I had in there? How do I do that?
Or is this not possible?

*This is not urgent as the contents inside were merely for learning purposes.*

Comment: My SQL Server service was put to manual when I first had the default instance, so it should of been properly off before the reset, however,
I've installed the SQL Server using the 2019 developer edition with basic setup after the fresh reset of my PC and it automatically generates a default instance and the Services tied to it and not to the copy that I had before my PC's reset. I don't know if theres a way to extract the user databases I've made or an installation setup method to use the copy of my default instance instead of creating a fresh default instance.

Comment: Just reinstall the instance, then reattach the databases. Hopefully they will come back online cleanly

Comment: @Charlieface When you say "reinstall the instance" do you mean the instance that has my database? how would I do that? if not, and you mean to connect to the instance that has my databases and to reattach that to the fresh instance, I checked on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/detach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15 and the issue is that I need to connect to it in the first place which is what I'm trying to work out, I'm trying to figure out how to do so after having freshly wiped my PC and only having a copy of the default instance that has my databases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand So there should be if I have a "Customer Registry" database, a "Customer Registry.mdf" that I move to the new default instance's DATA folder and follow the link you provided?

Comment: You install a new instance of SQL Server, then attach the database as above

Comment: @AaronBertrand It seems like I don't have the actual databases, the copy that I had seems like was garbage from when I was figuring out the default and named instances and the actual instance containing the databases was in part of my system that didn't allow backups for some reason... Your answer is correct since I've tried it out with the databases that I didn't need. I'll have to remake them and this time properly back them up.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been insightful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have two instances anymore. The instance you had before is gone because you wiped your PC. You installed a new instance, but it doesn't know anything about the databases you had created on your old instance.

With any luck, those databases were shut down cleanly and can simply be attached to your new instance (and are still actually on your hard drive after the "reset" - I don't know exactly what that means).

If the files are there, you should:

- manually copy all the user databases from the *old* instance's data folder to the *new* instance's data folder. This step isn't strictly necessary, but it's a good idea for sanity.
- create a [`CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database) command for each one, e.g.:

  ```
    CREATE DATABASE CustomerRegistry 
          ON (filename = 'C:\NewDataFolder\CustomerRegistry.mdf')
      LOG ON (filename = 'C:\NewDataFolder\CustomerRegistry.ldf')
    FOR ATTACH;
  ```

You'll also be missing any logins or jobs you created on the old instance, so you may have some manual reparations in those areas too.

If the files aren't there, well, this is why we use backups that we can put in a safe place outside of the current system, and that we can restore, instead of relying on old files scattered all over the place in questionable states.

Comment: Answer is correct, unfortunately the databases that I wanted were not in the instance that I had.